# CSRF token missing or incorrect on one page

Tags: django, python-2.6

Have a homepage there every page with a form works fine.
Added a form to my start page and in my local server it works fine.
But when I add it to the production server it does not work.
It say's that **CSRF- token is missing or incorret**.
But I have added the token, and it works all the other pages.

What is that I'm missing... ?

View

```
  @login_required
    def start(request) :
        libs = Library.objects.all();
        header = Header('Start');
        studies = None;
        source = None;
        if request.method == 'POST' :
            if 'Show_studie' in request.POST:
                studies = Study.objects.all;
            if 'Show_source' in request.POST:
                source = Source.objects.all;
        dctArgs = {
            'library_list': libs,
            'styles_dir': conf.styles_path,
            'header': header.html,
            'studies_list':studies,
            'source_list':source,
            'images_dir': conf.images_path,
            };
        return render_to_response('start.html', dctArgs, RequestContext(request));

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE></TITLE>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{styles_dir}}/common.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{styles_dir}}/header.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{styles_dir}}/Headerstyles.css" />
</HEAD>
<BODY>
{{header|safe}}
<h1></h1>
<table id="doc_tbl" class="data" cellspacing=0>
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Documents</th>
  <th>Export</th>
</tr>
{% for library in library_list %}
    <tr>
    <td><a href="/library_overview/{{library.id}}/">{{library.name}}</a></td>
    <td>{{library.source_set.all|length}}</td>
    <td><a href="/library_export/{{library.id}}/format/TS/">Andra till Jesper Export</a></td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
<h3>Messages</h3>
{{messages}}
</br>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="/start/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
<fieldset style="width:300px; margin-left:5px;">
<legend> Show all </legend>
<input type="checkbox" name="Show_studie" value="Show Studie"> Studie
<input type="checkbox" name="Show_source" value="Show Source"> Source
</br>
</br>
<input type="submit" value="Show All">
</fieldset>
{% if studies_list %}
<h3> Studies </h3>
<table class="table1">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th></th>
  <th scope="col1" >Name</th>
  <th scope="col1" >Added by</th>
</tr>
</thead>
{% for study in studies_list %}
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
  <a href="/define_study/{{study.id}}/edit/"><img class="icon" src="{{images_dir}}/edit-icon.png"/></a>
  &nbsp;
  <img onclick="javascript:return confirmDelete_name('Are you sure? The study and any associated information will be deleted.', {{study.id}}, 'delete_study');" class="icon" src="{{images_dir}}/delete-icon.png"/>
</td>
<td><a href="/define_study/{{study.id}}/">{{study.name}}</a></td>
<td>{{study.metadata_added_by_user.first_name}}&nbsp;{{study.metadata_added_by_user.last_name}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
{% endif %}
{% if source_list %}
<h3> Source </h3>
<table class="table1">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th></th>
  <th scope="col1" >Name</th>
  <th scope="col1" >Added by</th>
</tr>
</thead>
{% for source in source_list %}
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
  <a href="/define_study/{{study.id}}/edit/"><img class="icon" src="{{images_dir}}/edit-icon.png"/></a>
  &nbsp;
  <img onclick="javascript:return confirmDelete_name('Are you sure? The study and any associated information will be deleted.', {{study.id}}, 'delete_study');" class="icon" src="{{images_dir}}/delete-icon.png"/>
</td>
<td><a href="/define_study/{{study.id}}/">{{source.name}}</a></td>
<td>{{source.metadata_added_by_user.first_name}}&nbsp;{{source.metadata_added_by_user.last_name}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
</tbody>
</table>
</form> 
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
Help
Reason given for failure:
    CSRF token missing or incorrect.

In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when Django's
CSRF mechanism has not been used correctly. For POST forms, you need to ensure:
•   The view function uses RequestContext for the template, instead of Context.
•   In the template, there is a {% csrf_token %} template tag inside each POST form that   targets an internal URL.
•   If you are not using CsrfViewMiddleware, then you must use csrf_protect on any views
   that use the csrf_token template tag, as well as those that accept the POST data.
You're seeing the help section of this page because you have DEBUG = True in your Django   settings file. Change that to False, and only the initial error message will be displayed.
You can customize this page using the CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW setting.

Settings

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)
```

On the page that working I get this message:

```
<django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage object at 0x03B7A270>
```

Comment: Show us some details!

Comment: We cannot help you unless we see the code that you are using. So update the question with your `views.py` and your template that is causing the problem.

Comment: CRSF token works with cookies and HTTP headers. Did you change of web browser ? Can we have some information about your server & browser cookie policies, and about how you added the CSRF token ?

Comment: Did you add the CSRF middleware to your site?

Comment: Ah, here it is: `return render_to_response('start.html', dctArgs, RequestContext(request));` should be `return render_to_response('start.html', dctArgs, context_instance=RequestContext(request));`

Comment: @limelights Actually, `context_instance` is the third positional argument to `render_to_response`, so this won't make any difference. And please, please, please loose the semicolon (`;`).

Comment: @kingRauk Do you see the csrf token when you view the page source in your browser? Do you use javascript to post the form to the server, and if so, can you post the code?

Comment: @knbk yeah, lol, I had been coding javascript for a few hours so I didn't even notice it sneak in! :) Sorry for that!

Comment: @knbk No I can't see it, not if I look at the page source.

Comment: What do you see when you use `{{ request.csrf_token }}` in your template?

Comment: Did you add the `django.core.context_processors.request`?

Comment: I have found something. In page's that do work I got a hidden div with name="csrfmiddlewaretoken", but not on the page that don't work.

Comment: Did try {{ request.csrf_token }} but dindn't show anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your view in the `@requires_csrf_token` decorator, like so:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import requires_csrf_token

@requires_csrf_token
@login_required
def start(request):
    ...
```

Comment: It works now with this solution. Thanks @Vasily Alexeev Knbk Inforian and all for the help.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the csrf_exempt decorator to disable CSRF protection for a particular view.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
@csrf_exempt
def someview():
    ......
```

I know Its not what you want but you can try this if you want :)